# How to count number of records based on a filter in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to count the number of records in a group based on a filter operation I need to apply on the group

df

```
id dg cs
1  s  1
1  v  0
2  s  0
2  v  1
2  s  1
2  s  0
3  s  1
3  s  1
3  v  1
```

I need to count (or tag) the number of records for which there is an occurence of 's-1' combination in 'dg-cs' fields before a 'v' in 'dg'.

Hence the out put would be

```
id dg cs output
1  s  1  True
1  v  0  False
2  s  0  False
2  v  1  False
2  s  1  False
2  s  0  False
3  s  1  True
3  s  1  True
3  v  1  False
```

Comment: Is the behaviour you described independent of the `id` column? Or you want that behaviour for/within each `id`? Also, in your example all `s-1` combinations get a `True` value. Can you post a more representative example? (i.e. with a `s-1` case that is `False`).

Comment: @AntoniosK No, its dependent...behaviour is to be applied for each group of a particular id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My approach would be the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%  
  mutate(out = dg == "s" & cs == 1 & cumsum(dg == "v") == 0) 

## A tibble: 9 x 4
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id    dg    cs   out
#  <int> <chr> <int> <lgl>
#1     1     s     1  TRUE
#2     1     v     0 FALSE
#3     2     s     0 FALSE
#4     2     v     1 FALSE
#5     2     s     1 FALSE
#6     2     s     0 FALSE
#7     3     s     1  TRUE
#8     3     s     1  TRUE
#9     3     v     1 FALSE
```

The part `cumsum(dg == "v") == 0` means it can only be true if `dg=="v"` has not yet appeared for that particular id.

Comment: I somehow get all False as the output, I've checked that that the dg and cs fields are indeed chr and int types. I've also tried with using paranthesis, mutate(out = (dg == 's' & cs == 1 & (cumsum(dg == 'v') == 0)))

Comment: @hbabbar then either your sample data is wrong or your description

Comment: r3 <- df%>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(out = (cumsum(dg== "v") == 0))
On using this code, I find that there are still no Trues, could it be that the cumsum() is not working as expected. (My id field is of type numeric)

Comment: You need to check your own data. This is your job, not mine.. If your example is different than your actual data, I cannot help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was more of a doubt over the working of cumsum() rather than checking the sanctity of the data, which i know is my job.

Comment: I can assure you that `cumsum` is working as expected. Did you make sure you understand the logic behind it?